# How to show the position of a letter on a matrix?

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

Today Im practicing with matrices by doing a hangman game.

So far I have already managed to get the program to compare the letter that the user inserts and, if it finds it is equal to one of the letters of the word, it will give the position of the letter in numbers (0,1,2,3 etc).

```
void hangman(char word[],int size){
int counter=0;


while(counter<=7){


    printf("\nInsert a letter: ");
    char letter;
    scanf("%c",&letter);
    fflush(stdin);
    if(letter==word[counter++]){
        printf("\nThe letters position is %d\n",counter-1);
    }else{
        if(letter!=word[counter++]){
            imprimirMatriz(y,4,7);
            printf("\nThat letter is not part of the word!\n");
            printf("Try again.\n");
        }
    }


}
```

}

Now, so far, so good. It gives the position of the letter and that is awesome, however, I made a matrix of one row and eight columns and what I would like to do is to get the program to show the position of the letter on that matrix. For example, if the word is "although" and the indexed  letter is "a", it has to print the matrix as "a _ _ _ _ _ _ _".

Any help you guys could provide me would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array for the masked string.
example:

```
given string = 'abcd'
array1 = ['a']['b']['c']['d']
array2 = ['_']['_']['_']['_']
```

When the player guesses a letter existed in the given string, you can assign values of the masked string to the correct letter or the corresponding values of the given string. It's easy to return the masked string now.

Example:
A player guess the letter 'a' -> true
index of 'a' in array1 is 0 -> array2[0] = 'a' -> return array2 as a string: 'a _ _ _'